# trying to unset my session['where'] not only clicking on my submit input... but also with page refresh

Tags: php

I have a list of posts in my page, and I also have a form to search for posts.

This is my form:

```
<form  action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="search"  onclick="if(this.value=='Search:')this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Search:'" value="Search:" />
  <input type="submit" value="Search"  name="sendForm" />
</form>
```

And then, when my form is submited with some values I store a session with my sql condition statment and I get only my list of news that have title like the value I wrote in my input.

And then, If I submit my form without any value I unset my session and I get my list of all news again.

```
if(isset($_POST['sendForm'])){
    $search = $_POST['search'];
    if(!empty($search) && $search != 'Search:'){
    $_SESSION['where'] = "WHERE title LIKE '%$search%'";
        header('Location: dashboard.php?exe=posts/index');
    }
    else{
        unset($_SESSION['where']);
    }
 }
```

And this is working fine, but I need to click on my input search to unset my session and get all news again.

Even if I refresh my page Im getting only my news with title that I wrote in my input, and only if I click on my submit button I get again my list with all news.

Do you see how I can solve this, how I can unset my session not only clicking on my submit again but also with page refresh, becausee I want to show all news when I click in my link dashboard.php?exe=posts/index

Im trying with this code below on top of my page, but like this my search form is not working, is not returning any results.

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['where'])){
  unset($_SESSION['where']);    
}
```

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to SQL injection attacks!

Comment: Agree with Daniel.  Have a look at [SQL_injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: So please explain, why are you saving the WHERE condition in the SESSION var? This might help with response.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Im using my session to store my WHERE condition so I can do my sql statment like: $read = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts {$_SESSION['where']} ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT ?,?");

Comment: @OzzC that still isn't safe.

Answer (score 1):

Another quick alternative is instead of unset, you can set `$_SESSION['where'] == ""` then your query will not be affected as it does only contains nothing. Also please take note that your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attack.

Comment: Thanks UserProg, I already use that before my sql statment like this: $_SESSION['where'] = isset($_SESSION['where']) ? $_SESSION['where'] : '';

Comment: But my problem still remains, however Im here now trying to understand why my code is vulnerable to sql injection and how I can solve it, because I never work against sql injection and dont know how we can do !

Comment: solve the problem of your where statement first. try to echo your query and also your $_SESSION['where'] if no input is given and see what you have in there.

Comment: Thank you! When I write in my form "arriv" and I submit and it returned two results. And my echo is like: WHERE title LIKE '%arriv%'. And then I refresh my page and my echo still remains like WHERE titleLIKE '%arriv%'

Comment: well that is expected because you did not set anything back to your $_SESSION['where']. the result will appear on the next page after you click search right? because I can see you are using header. In this case, in you dashboard.php why don't you put another form with the button to reset the search? Then you can set back your $_SESSION['where'] to ""

Answer (score 0):

You could store the user last visited page in session, and if it's the same than your current page and there is no submit, you know that it's a refresh.

Alternatively you could use the `referer` (`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`) although it's less reliable because it's client data and can be tampered.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Loic, but I really dont understand your solution for my issue. I´m sorry, can you please explain better?